# How do I force a failed ValidationResult with FluentValidation

Tags: null, fluentvalidation

I want to check for a null object before validating with FluentValidation. 
If the object is null I want to force a failed validation result. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer (in a SO discussion about null objects sent to FV):

```
ValidationResult failedResult = new ValidationResult(
       new[] { 
          new ValidationFailure("", "Data is null."),  
       });
```

So in a class with members of validation and data, instantiated previously (in constructor or initiation functions) I could use:

```
public ValidationResult Validate()
{ 
    if ( this.data == null )
       return new ValidationResult(
          new[] { new ValidationFailure("", "Data is null."),  });
   else return this.validation.Validate(data);
}
```

Comment: link to SO discussion?